# Java Android - Rotate bitmap after drawn

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I've made arraylists for multiple bitmaps, matrices and paints, and I would like to change them dynamically in my main thread.  This is my drawview (cut some code to shorten it):

```
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap1);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
        matrixArray.add(matrix2);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paintArray.add(paint);
}   

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i), matrixArray.get(i), paintArray.get(i));
    }
}



public void translate(int Num, float x, float y){
    matrixArray.get(Num).postTranslate(x,y);

}
```

What i'd like is to call drawview.translate from my main thread like so:

```
drawView.translate(Num, image.getX(), image.getY()); //image is a moving imageview
```

I couldn't find much about using the main thread to control a drawn bitmap so if anyone could explain I'd greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a way to draw my bitmap and move/rotate it on my command:

In my OnDraw(){

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, null, rectf, sPaint);
```

Movable using the rectF, and to rotate:

```
rotation = ((float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((fingery - rectf.centerY()),(fingerx - rectf.centerX())));

       matrix.setRotate(rotation2+90, rectf.centerX(), rectf.centerY());
       bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

I was having trouble when my bitmap rotated, it changed size. I fixed it using:

```
       rectf.right = rectf.centerX() + bitmap1.getWidth()/2;
       rectf.left = rectf.centerX() - bitmap1.getWidth()/2;
       rectf.top = rectf.centerY() - bitmap1.getHeight()/2;
       rectf.bottom = rectf.centerY() + bitmap1.getHeight()/2;
```

I hope this helps some people!